# Copy files over network while creating these files

Tags: command-line, rsync, scp

My Situation: I want to copy a file from one PC to another. Unfortunately this file isn't complete. There is a process appending data to this file (only at the end).

Is there a way to easily copy this file without having to start from the beginning each time the copy-tool thinks, it finished?

Is there for example any possibility to tell tools like scp/rsync/whatever to wait for example 20 seconds after finishing a download - and if the file changes, just download this extra bit of data?

Or is there maybe a way to let the download start with byte X?

Does anyone know a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need the file while its size increases, or only after the file is "finished".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would have been to have the process that is creating the file also create the remote file at the same time. Either by writing directly to the remote location or by using something like `tee` to both pipe data to, for example, an `ssh` connection and to a local file. That should have been done when you started the process though.

Since the file is already being created, yes, you can use `rsync` for it. By default, `rsync` only copies the updated data so if you just run `rsync` every few minutes, you will get what you want. You could use a brute force approach:

```
while :; do rsync -u source destination; sleep 20; done
```

That will run in an endless loop, copying `source` to `destination` only if `source` is different. Once the process that is creating the file has finished, you can stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

A more elegant way would be to monitor the file. If it is being created on `machineA` and copied to `machineB`, you could do this from `machineB` (this assumes you have passwordless `ssh` set up):

```
while [[ $(ssh machineA md5sum < /path/to/file) != $(md5sum < /path/to/file) ]] do 
    rsync -uv aa b
    sleep 20
done
```

Note that this will stop the first time the two files are the same. If you file creation process doesn't write for more than 20 seconds and then resumes, you will have to copy again manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The -u parameter of rsync seems quite useful :).

Answer (score 1):

You might look into using **incron** for your **rsync** to run when file changes, i.e. **IN_MODIFY**, if this is a long term file sync you need.

http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2014/158/Monitoring-with-incron

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man5/incrontab.5.html

If it's short term, terdon's last while loop may be quicker to setup.